# Help transcoding simple jQuery to mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, transcoding

```
$(".container").hover(
     function(){
              $(".child-1").hide(0);
              $(".child-2").show(0);
     },function(){
              $(".child-1").show(0);
              $(".child-2").hide(0);
});
```

A project I have requires that I use mootools, but I never used mootools, and jquery makes much more sense to me. Can someone show me how this example would look like in mootools?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MooTools uses two shorthand methods: `$`, and `$$`

```
<div id="someId">..</div>
<p class="someClass">..</p>

Jquery           | MooTools
-------------------------------
$("#someId")     | $("someId")
$(".someClass")  | $$(".someClass");
```

In MooTools, $ is only used to search elements by ID, and $$ is for everything else. So the above can be implemented as:

```
$$(".container").addEvents({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $$(".child-1").hide();
        $$(".child-2").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $$(".child-1").show();
        $$(".child-2").hide();
    }
});
```

*.hide() and .show() are shortcut methods that are part of [`Element.Shortcuts`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts#Element:hide) in MooTools-More, but you could define these yourselves if you want.*

But, if you're comfortable with the jQuery syntax and it makes you productive, checkout this project [`Mooj`](http://github.com/cheeaun/mooj) by Lim Chee Aun. It allows you to use an almost jQueryish syntax in MooTools.

If you have no particular reason to use only MooTools, checkout how to use [MooTools with jQuery](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools) on David Walsh's blog.

If you'd like to use jQuery for the DOM and MooTools for the object-oriented goodiness, checkout [this article](http://ryanflorence.com/object-oriented-jquery-with-mootools-pigs-take-flight/) by Ryan Florence.

And finally for a great side-by-side comparison of both frameworks, checkout this [definitive article](http://jqueryvsmootools.com/) by Aaron Newton.

Comment: do NOT use native mouseover/mouseout but use mouseenter/mouseleave instead (fixes mouseover on child elements and event bubbling)

Comment: @Oskar - thats why copy/paste is a bad idea